# Will Bluetooth work?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm in the market for a new laptop. I'm looking at DELL Inspiron 15 3000 15.6". I've only ever used old laptops before so wanted to check something.

This laptop comes with Bluetooth, when I dual boot Ubuntu on it, will the Bluetooth still work?? I assume Ubuntu will go fine on here in general??

Comment: Bluetooth under Ubuntub16.04 kernel 4.7.3 works with my Dell Inspiron17R SE 7720 but that is no guarantee for you.

Answer (score 1):

Laptop vendors install different Wifi+BT modules to the same laptop models.

Hence there is no guarantee that BT will work, since not all BT adapers are supported by Linux kernel. If you could find out which adapter is installed, it will be possible to tell if it is supported.

Atheros, Intel and Broadcom chips are supported.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a definite answer unless I get the exact same laptop, but yes, Bluetooth should work in Ubuntu. Of course, it all depends on what you'll be using Bluetooth for and how you define "working." (e.g. browsing files on Bluetooth-connected Android sometimes doesn't work, Bluetooth headsets sometimes play only in Mono, etc)

Comment: The Bluetooth earbuds default to mono but I just needed to go into System Settings, Sound, select device and change interface to A2DP.

Comment: Every time I select that, it changes back. Might just be an issue with my adapter or earbuds though, because it took 3 tries to get it paired on the first place.